# Cannot implicitly convert 'void' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, string

In the code snippet below, this line:

```
if (player.Manager.Chat.Say(plr, user))
```

Results in an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert 'void' to 'bool'

[image]

Why am I getting this error?

```
internal class AFKCommand : Command
{
    private AFKCommand() : base("afk", 0) { }
    protected override bool Process(Player player, RealmTime time, string[] args)
    {
        string user = player.Client.Account.Name;
        var plr = player.Manager.FindPlayer(user);
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            if (args[0] == "on")
            {
                if (player.Manager.Chat.Say(plr, user))
                {
                    plr.Manager.Chat.Say(plr, "I am AFK at the moment. This message was sent using the AFK feature. Type /afk for info");
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretend you don't know anything about your problem and read through your question. You'll find it's very vague and difficult to understand. Please  be more specific; what do you mean by "make a text a string meaning a certain thing"? What is `player`, or `Manager`, or `Chat` or `Say`? Is this code you wrote yourself? How does any of this relate to the `AFKCommand` that magically appears in the second half of the question?

Comment: The second half is just the full thing, if people wanted it to understand it more... player is the player and Manager is the manager and Chat is the Chat and Say is what is said in the chat.. I want to be able to use `user` in where `String text` is supposed to be but `user` obviously is not a "TEXT" but I don't know how I would go about that. I don't really feel like describing how the whole thing works... everything else works fine and functionally, just need to know what I asked above.

Comment: user is a string, text is a string they **are** the same type.

Comment: When you say "`user` obviously is not a 'TEXT'"; no, that isn't obvious at all. I have no idea what `user` is supposed to be, or even what a `TEXT` is. Maybe you forgot to add a tag that would indicate this is some library or framework that I don't know about. Right now this is just tagged C# and string.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin When I say "Text" i mean just regular String text, hence the quotation marks, figured people would understand that.. and user is a string that equals player.Name

Comment: @MarkHall I've tried using user where `String text` is supposed to be and I get an error saying Cannot convert 'void' to 'bool'

Comment: @RDR Ok, so when you say "TEXT", you mean the type `string`? If so, `user` *is* a `string` according to the declaration in your third snippet, and there's no problems passing it into that method. What's the issue?

Comment: Hi @RDR - This question has been put on hold due to it being very unclear. Please edit your post down to specific issues you're having. We do not know anything about your application; keep that in mind. If possible, try to use standard terminology, such as `string` instead of `text`. Show us a very minimal amount of code, as well as your *expected* behaviour and *actual* behaviour. Try to keep the background story/irrelevant details to a minimum. Once the post has been edited it'll be put up for review to be reopened.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I get an error saying _Cannot implicitly convert 'void' to 'bool'_

Comment: show the exact code, that gives that error. put a breakpoint on your statement and step into it to see exactly where your error is.

Comment: @RDR Well that means somewhere in your code the result of a void returning method is being returned or assigned or passed where a `bool` is expected. No way to tell where that is from your code.

Comment: With your edit, the problem is that `Say` returns nothing. Since it doesn't return anything, there's nothing to check. An `if` statement expects a boolean value. What is the intention of that if clause, in plain words?

Comment: If a player says `user` which is just the users name which the server finds when it is mentioned using the `var plr = ...` then the `plr` which is the player thats name is mentioned by `player` says something back in the chat.

Comment: @RDR I'm assuming `player.Manager.Chat.Say(plr, message)` is supposed to insert a message into the chat saying `message` from `player` to `plr`. This doesn't help you check anything, it only changes the state of the chat. From your last comment it still isn't clear what exactly you're trying to check in the `if`statement. E.g. can you fill out the blank in this sentence: "If _____, then I want to send an AFK message".

Comment: Ok. Here is my best explanation. @AsadSaeeduddin

_plr_ is the person who goes afk... _player_ is the person who mentions _plrs_ name while they are afk, if _player_ sends message containing the _plrs_ name, then _player_ sends a message in the chat saying "I am afk..."..

very summarized version:
when player says plrs name, plr sends a message back

Comment: @RDR Ok, I think I understand now. You want A to happen when B happens (where A is "an AFK notification is sent" and B is "an AFK player is mentioned"). What you want is to move this `if` statement into a portion of the code that is executed *every time anyone sends a message*. At that time, you need to check if the target of the message is AFK (using some property or method of the target player object, e.g. `targetPlayer.IsAFK`), and if so, dispatch this message. Hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want text to mean something then you can either make an enumeration

```
enum Test
{
    A,
    B
}
```

Then use `Test.A` or `Test.A.ToString()`

or use a SortedList where you can store your results.

I don't however completely understand your question.